# Using sequence in MySQL and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sequence, auto-generate

I'm working on a project that uses Hibernate and MySQL. I intend to use sequence to generate ID for all tables in database. (It's hard to describe my question, so I will show you as an example).

For example: I have 2 tables A & B. Firstly, I insert 10 records to table A, and **their IDs will be 1 to 10**. Then, I insert 10 records to table B, and I want **their IDs will be 11-20**, not 1-10. It means the generated ID value will be counted by all records in all tables in databases, not in a single table.

So how can I use that concept in MySQL? Declare and syntax?
In Hibernate, how can I use the strategy and generator on data model to apply that generated strategy in database?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have sequences in Mysql, but you can use the 'TABLE' id generation

```
@javax.persistence.TableGenerator(
    name="EMP_GEN",
    table="GENERATOR_TABLE",
    pkColumnName = "key",
    valueColumnName = "hi"
    pkColumnValue="EMP",
    allocationSize=20
)

@Entity
public class Klass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator=EMP_GEN)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

You might need to add the snippet `@javax.persistence.TableGenerator [...]` in all your entities

### Edit

> Thank you so much. But do we have another way to use that snippet without adding it to each entity? And when creating tables on database, how can I declare the ID primary key column for DBMS to auto-generate the value like that? – napoleonit76

Unfortunately, I don't know an elegant way to do this :(. In my project, we use the a sequence in several entities, and we need to declare the sequence in each class. 
One thing you could try (but I don't really like) is to create a super class for all of your entities, and that superclass only contains the ID field and the annotations. I have the feeling that I've seen this in a project, but I'm not 100% sure.

About telling the DB to use that strategy, I don't think it's really possible. You can try to add a trigger and apply it to each table in the schema. The trigger will fire when you insert a new row in the table, pick a value from the **generator table**, and add it to the row. I honestly don't know if this might work, and I'm 99% sure that this won't work if you have 2 concurrent sessions creating rows.

Can you rethink your strategy and use normal auto-increment columns for the ids and put the sequential number in another column of your tables?

Comment: Thank you so much. But do we have another way to use that snippet without adding it to each entity? And when creating tables on database, how can I declare the ID primary key column for DBMS to auto-generate the value like that?

Comment: @Augusto I have a similar problem.  Are you willing to help me with it also?  here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252541/generatedvalue-for-a-java-abstract-superclass-over-mysql

Comment: Avoid using `GenerationType.TABLE` because It entails pessimistic locks to generate unique values. However, If you still want to use it then also use some optimization techniques (e.g. `pooled`) to reduce the additional database queries. Use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead.