# Generating Part of A Hibernate Composite ID With A Sequence

Tags: java, hibernate

Given a composite id/PK class like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class ModelObjectPK implements Serializable {

    private String employeeId;
    private Long transactionId;

    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return this.employeeId;
    }

    @Column(name="TX_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE name="TX_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TX_SEQ" sequenceName="S_TX")
    public Long getTransactionId() {
        return this.transactionId;
    }

    // setters
}
```

Since I've seen some answers lean towards no, some say "well, the spec says this...", and some answers referencing version of Hibernate dating back to the stone age, I have this question:

**Yes or No**: Can I use a sequence generator to generate one portion of a Composite ID?

The version of Hibernate I'm concerned with is version 4.1.3.

Comment: Which DB? MySQL does not support sequence generation (at least so far as I remember and according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015766/using-sequence-in-mysql-and-hibernate))

Comment: Okay, good point. In this case, yes, I am using a DB that supports sequences.

Comment: I tried to find some info but I did not come out with nothing sure. My understanding is that is doable (for instance ObjectDB support GeneratedValue also for normal columns and there is no constraint into the JPA specification), but it seems that Hibernate support sequence only in conjunction with `@Id`. Now I am curious to know the answer if someone can provide it!

Comment: Right. It's legal to have a model object that has multiple fields tagged with @Id, but then the identifier ends up being the entire object. This isn't an acceptable solution for my project. I've done similar research, who no luck, hence me asking for a simple Yes/No answer.