# My Sql Auto Increment not working Properly its increment 3 by 3 records

Tags: java, mysql

my project using Auto increment in my hybernate entity table. every new records is save then

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

the "id" is auto increment 3 by 3. like

```
1051
1054
1057
```

any solution to fix this issue. please help me.

Comment: can you paste the o/p of `show create table` command in mysql ?

Comment: Why do you care about the id generation if you use `GenerationType.AUTO`? Why don't you use `SEQUENCE` instead?

Comment: @Flown MySQL doesn't support `SEQUENCE`

Comment: hi @Flown my project already set entity field id is GenerationType.AUTO. SEQUENCE
The SEQUENCE generator (defined in the SQL:2003 standard) is supported by:
Oracle
SQL Server
PostgreSQL
DB2
HSQLDB  only. here not support mysql. >> https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-identity-sequence

Comment: My question persists. Why do you care about the id generation if you're using the `AUTO` type? `SEQUENCE` was just a random example. If MySQL doesn't support `SEQUENCE` you have to use `TABLE` for example instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a sequence in your db. It will make it auto increment sequentially.

[here is the more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015766/using-sequence-in-mysql-and-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Its My SQL DB Fault.

default db system  auto increment value is set 3 that's call its Auto incremented 3 by 3 every insert.

If  u want to check and update mysql system auto increment value then

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;

Then its fixed thanks guys.

More info >> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html